# Aframe play 360º video without wating

Tags: video-streaming, aframe

I want to play a 360 video with Aframe. My video is mp4 format with 360 meta activated. The video has 5 minutes, if I put it into a normal http server, clients must to wait until the video download to browser.. a lot of time. Which strategy could be the best approach to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

i use a splashscreen so you can preload a bit before playing the video this should help a bit :-) [Aframe splashscreen if videopsphere loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52203852/aframe-splashscreen-if-videopsphere-loads)

ps.: do you use 4K videos?